# Why am I for this simple task getting the Timed out error even if the arrays are not that big?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm doing a task on codility.com, and I am getting a Timed Out error. The code and task description are below.

Text of the task (the arrays are initialized): `class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }` that, given an array `A` of `N` integers, **returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in `A`**.

For example, given `A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]`, the function should return `5`. Given `A = [1, 2, 3]`, the function should return `4`. Given `A = [−1, −3]`, the function should return `1`.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions: `N` is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array `A` is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int k;
        for (int i = 1;; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            if (!Arrays.stream(A).anyMatch(x -> x != j)) {
                k = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question does not state the contents of A anywhere. So it not reproducible by others.

Comment: what is code *supposed* to do, have you analyzed how many comparisons it does for *some* sample input?

Comment: I think `for (int i = 1;; i++)` leads to an endless loop

Comment: @B001ᛦ But that is not necessarily an issue. There is still a way to exit the loop.

Comment: @B001ᛦ since there is a `break` inside the loop it *can* exit, it will not always lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: @luk2302 yes! makes sense  ;)

Comment: @luk2302 That depends on the contents of A... generally, it is, for a public method, a bad idea to rely on the validity of the input to avoid an endless loop.

Comment: Text of the  task(the arrays are initialized):

class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Not if the task / assignment was specified to have proper input but OP left that out completely. In the "real" world I agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your array `A` doesn't contain any positive numbers. Thus your loop does not break.

**O(n log n)** solution:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    final int solution[] = {1};
    Arrays.stream(A)
            .filter(i -> i > 0)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(i -> {
                if (i == solution[0]) {
                    solution[0]++;
                }
            });
    return solution[0];
}
```

**O(n)** solution:

```
 public int solution2(int[] A) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
    Arrays.stream(A)
            .filter(i -> i > 0)
            .forEach(bitSet::set);
    return bitSet.nextClearBit(1);
}
```

Comment: I had assumed the OP had corrected the code as per Eran's answer, but you are right. It's still wrong in the question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought i corrected that before posting.

Comment: @ETO thanks man. It is working.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Nope. In this particular case there is no difference. As `IntStream.of(int... values)` calls `Arrays.stream(values)` anyway. Please consult the source code of static method `java.util.stream.IntStream.of(int...)`.

Comment: @ETO Good point, `Arrays.stream()` is overloaded. It's Arrays.asList(A).stream()` which wouldn't work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, exactly. `Arrays.stream(int[])` calls `java.util.Arrays#stream(int[] array, int startInclusive, int endExclusive)` with appropriate values. Arrays.stream(int...) has the same output as `IntStream.of(int...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an O(N*m) algorithm which is going to be inefficient.

I suggest using a different strategy which passes the array only once. O(n) e.g. use a BitSet to record which positive numbers are present. Then find the first missing entry in the BitSet. e.g. `BitSet.nextBitClear(1)`

A simpler solution is to sort the array and find the first missing element, however, this is O(n ln n) which is slower but might be fast enough.

Comment: Being O(n log n) does not necessarily imply that a sorting solution is slower. That’s especially true for the given numbers and examples, i.e. numbers in the the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000] range, but rather small arrays. Here, I’d go for the sorting rather than `BitSet`, considering that the actual implementations in recent JDKs perform the sorting better than n log n on average…

Comment: @Holger Given the range of N is 100,000 it's tempting to assume they have an array with 1 ... 99,999 entries, or at least that is what I would try. Ideally, you would have two implementations selected based on the size of the array.

Comment: @Holger In any case, if n is small, an O(n^2) algo is fine as well. esp if you make sure the code is warmed up first. e.g. dropping the use of Stream might make more difference if warm up is poor.

Comment: Just considered that the solution must be within the array length or be array length plus one if the array contains all consecutive numbers, hence, the bit set needs at most the size of the array length (specified to be at most 100,000), not the 1,000,000 as we can skip all numbers outside the range and even reduce the number range to consider (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53189177/2711488)). Then, the bit set might outperform all other solutions.

Comment: The bit set might be best for worst case, but as you suggest, if there was a lot of call for short arrays, avoiding the allocation would be best. I think this style of optimisation would be more likely to help in real world problems.

Comment: Well, in my solution, I first specified a capacity to the `BitSet`, to avoid expansion operations, but then decided against it, as is indeed possible that the required capacity is much smaller or that the bitset even stays empty during the entire operation. Due to the dynamic adaptation of the range, this is not unlikely. In these cases, the allocation of the bit set is quiet cheap and not worse than allocating a stream or whatever else you would use for temporary storage. And the code complexity is not higher than the other other solution’s.

Answer (score 1):

Your program only terminates if all the elements of the input array are identical (in which case it returns the value of that element).

Otherwise, you have an infinite loop.

`Arrays.stream(A).anyMatch(x -> x != j)` is `true` if and only if any of the elements of the array is not equal to `j`. Therefore `!Arrays.stream(A).anyMatch(x -> x != j)` is `true` if and only if all the elements of the array are equal to `j`, which can only happen if all the elements of the array are equal.

If you change the condition to `!Arrays.stream(A).anyMatch(x -> x == j)`, your program now searches for the smallest positive `int` that doesn't appear in the input array. If you still get a timeout for that, this means you are expected to implement the algorithm more efficiently.

Instead of iterating from 1 to n until you find a number not in the array (and in each iteration going over the input array), you can find the smallest positive `int` not in the array with at most two iterations over the array elements (this can be done, for example, by putting the elements of the array in a `TreeSet<Integer>`, and then iterating over the `Set`'s elements until you find the smallest positive number not in the `Set`).

Comment: Sorry my fault insted of == i set !=. Thanks you.

Comment: @JasminJaskoMerušić are you saying the code that timed out had `if (!Arrays.stream(A).anyMatch(x -> x == j))`?

Comment: The problem here was that i insted of== i have put !=. Answered the question with that.

Answer (score 1):

For an efficient solution, you should consider that for any solution *n*, the array must contain at least all *n-1* positive numbers, hence must have at least the length *n-1*. This allows in turn, to draw the conclusion that the solution can never be greater than the array length plus one.

So all we have to record, are the positive numbers smaller than this limit. Further, each value outside that range reduces the number of array elements available for the *n-1* elements, hence, allows us to reduce the range even further.

[As suggested by Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187540/2711488), you can use a `BitSet` for recording the encountered values within the possible solution range. This class also has an efficient built-in operation for finding the first cleared bit, which matches the smallest unencountered value.

```
public int solution(int[] a) {
    int limit = a.length;
    BitSet encountered = new BitSet();
    for(int value: a)
        if(value < 1 || value > limit) limit--; else encountered.set(value);
    return encountered.nextClearBit(1);
}
```